# Transit Visa for Thailand

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand

Im an Indian citizen. Do I need a transit visa in Thailand while going to Angkor Wat from Kolkata (India), and can I stay in Thailand for two days on this transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

You would not need a visa to transit Thailand, when you're making a connection of not more than 12 hours. For a long period, such as a two-day visit, you would need to secure a transit visa in advance.

From [Thailand's Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.go.th/main/en/services/4908/15398-Issuance-of-Visa.html)

> **Transit Visa**
>   This type of visa may be issued to applicants who wish to enter the Kingdom for the following purposes:
>
> - To travel in transit through the Kingdom in order to proceed to a third country (category “TS”)
> - To participate in sports activities (category “S”)
> - To perform duty as person in charge, or crew member of a conveyance coming to a port, station or area in the Kingdom (category “C”)
>
> **Documents required**:
>
> - Passport or travel document in lieu of passport with validity of not less than 6 months
> - Visa application form duly filled in
> - One (4x5 cm.) photograph of the applicant
> - Proof of means of transportation (for example confirmed air ticket paid in full)
> - Evidence of adequate means of subsistence, i.e.10,000 Baht per person and 20,000 Baht per family
> - Documents substantiating the indicated purpose of visit (for example, visa of a third country in the passport or travel document or letter of invitation stating the applicant’s participation in sports activities in the Kingdom)
> - Additional documents may be required as deemed necessary
>
> **Fee**:
>   25 Euros per entry
>
> **Validity of Visa**
>   The validity of visa, as indicated on the visa page (“Enter before …”), is the length of time during which the holder of the visa is entitled to present himself/herself at a Thai immigration checkpoint with a view to entering into the Kingdom of Thailand. It does not indicate the length of time the holder of the visa may stay in the Kingdom. The validity of a single entry Transit Visa is 3 months from date of issuance and that of a two-entry, three-entry or four-entry Transit Visa may be 3 or 6 months from date of issuance.
>
> **Period of Stay**
>   The period of stay in the Kingdom of Thailand is not to be confused with the validity of the visa. While the latter is indicated on the visa page, the period of stay (or each stay for a two-entry, three-entry or four-entry Transit Visa) will be determined upon arrival at a Thai immigration checkpoint by the immigration officer (“Admitted Until …” stamped on passport page). Holders of a Transit Visa may be granted entry and permitted to stay in the Kingdom at the discretion of the immigration officer for a period not exceeding 30 days.
>
> **Transit Passengers**
>   Passengers transiting at an airport in the Kingdom with a view to catching a scheduled connecting flight within 12 hours of their arrival without the intention of clearing immigration procedure, do not require a visa. They must however be inspected by the competent authorities upon arrival and must stay only in designated areas of the airport until their departure. All passengers transiting at an airport in the Kingdom for more than 12 hours must obtain a transit visa prior to their arrival.